# Extract value from formatted text with bash

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, bioinformatics

I've got a .fasta file, which is strictly a formatted text containing some informations about DNA. 
Here's its common structure:

```
>NODE_18_length_75451_cov_83.3021
TGAACCGCTTGCCAAATATTTTCCGTCCGGACTTACGGCAACGGAAAGGAC
>NODE_3_length_175235_cov_84.0427
ACATGCAATGTTTATAGTCCTTGTATCAGAGACTCTATCAACGCTCTCGG
```

On even lines you've got the DNA sequence, and on odd lines you've got infos about the sequence. This scheme is repeated for at least 10k lines, into a single text file. I need to find a way to get only the value after "cov_" for every lines, to multiplicate it for 2 and print into a new file.
The new file needs to have this scheme (for all the lines):

```
>NODE_18 cov_166.60
DNA seq: TGAACCGCTTGCCAAATATTTTCCGTCCGGACTTACGGCAACGGAAAGGAC
>NODE_3 cov_168.04
DNA seq: ACATGCAATGTTTATAGTCCTTGTATCAGAGACTCTATCAACGCTCTCGG
```

Comment: Did you already tried something? Please post!

Comment: @JigglyNaga answer actually did the work. Tryin' to improve for doing the real task needed: when fixed, I'll update the quest with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use the shell for this, you can hand the arithmetic over to another command, like `bc`:

```
while read odd ; do
    echo -n "cov_" ; echo "2*${odd##*_}" | bc -q
    read even
    echo "DNA seq: $even"
done < input.fasta
```

Comment: It doesn't print actually what I'm looking for.
"cov." value where cutted off in the output.

Comment: Sorry, I slipped up while renaming variables.  Fixed.

Comment: can i grep letters from each even lines to calculate the % of G and C of every even line inside the loop? Tried as here, ( https://pastebin.com/Gb2w13dJ ) don't know why it doesn't work.
Could you please give a look?

Comment: The shell runs this loop once for each pair of input lines; it can't backtrack, or read the same line again.  If you add a `grep` (reading from stdin) into the loop, that will consume the whole of the rest of the file on the first run.  You'd have to find some other way to count characters (which could be eg. `echo $even | grep`).

Comment: Updated. Seems to work, except for "Dna cont" : it stamps for every line "50%" which is, obviously, not correct.
Could you give a look? https://pastebin.com/ZYcCwUVU

Comment: If you've encountered a new problem, please ask a new question: try to cut it down to a Minimum Working Example, and you might even be able to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

With bash? don't go there, it's not a text processing language. With awk:

```
awk -F_ '/^>/ {printf "%s_%s cov_%.2f\n", $1, $2, $6 * 2; next} {print "DNA seq:", $0}' file.fasta 
>NODE_18 cov_166.60
DNA seq: TGAACCGCTTGCCAAATATTTTCCGTCCGGACTTACGGCAACGGAAAGGAC
>NODE_3 cov_168.09
DNA seq: ACATGCAATGTTTATAGTCCTTGTATCAGAGACTCTATCAACGCTCTCGG
```

Comment: Is it possible to do more complex arithmetic operations into the printf argument? If I need to multiplicate and divide the $6 for other variables, did I need to do hand arithmetic over a "while..done" ?

Comment: @Shred `printf` arguments can be any valid expression AFAIK - beyond that, I'm unclear exactly what you're asking

Comment: In my case, for the cov. value i don't need to do just a *2 , but an operation where this value where divided for another variable (called, for example, K_MER). Could I do an operation like $6 / $K_MER into the printf argument? How can I use parenthesis to do that?

Comment: @Shred Arithmetic in `awk` follows [the usual rules of operator precedence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PEMDAS.html) however `$K_MER` would refer to the *field* whose number is equal to the value of variable `K_MER` - for the value itself, drop the `$`